# Ace responsive template jqGrid serach box ui issue

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid, media-queries

I am using
http://responsiweb.com/themes/preview/ace/1.3.5/jqgrid.html
In mobile view when user click on search icon of grid a modal popup shows up with some drop down option. But those dropdown option are not visible properly in mobile view.
I am not a css media query expert, please help me in find the cause.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which web browser you use in your test and on which device? I can't reproduce the problem. Moreover you use Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.0.1 as jqGrid, which I don't know enough. I develop *alternative fork* of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which have native support of Bootstrap. One can relatively easy customize the look of free jqGrid to be like on the pictures which you use.

Comment: One need just creates new `iconSet` which uses `baseIconSet: "fontAwesome"` (see the comment to [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/5b538ed571cdf15fbf5e39f02fff840cf821166f)) and `guiStyles`, which uses `baseGuiStyle: "bootstrap"` (like [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.0/js/grid.base.js#L754-L766))

Comment: @Oleg thanks for looking into it.
I am able to reproduce on your demo page as well.
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-bootstrap.htm
open the link chrome browser and and switch to mobile view in the browser itself.
and then check by opening the any dropdown. 
Open page size option dropdown, you will see issue.

Comment: I don't know any "mobile view" in Chrome, but one can *emulate* another devices. Which one should I emulate? I tried someone before posting my above comments, but I couldn't see any cases where the text was cut like on your screenshot,

Comment: I am using chrome browser open the link in chrome browser and then press F12 and click on the small mobile icon at left bottom to switch to mobile device view and then try to open any drop down on page you will see the issue.

Comment: @Oleg Added image in the detail also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105490/discussion-between-pawanplus-and-oleg).

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved with latest version of chrome browser 49 and in the mobile devices is working fine. Still appears in some real device but overall is working fine.